# Open a window at the same position of an already opened window wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a window that contains a menu, in this menu I have a button that opens a new window.

My problem is, I want this second window to be at the same place as first window, in order to have an effect like if it is the same window

Is there a way to get this done? Or are there another solutions?

Comment: Why not just add an overlay in the current window?

Comment: You can use Window.Top and Window.Left to get and set the position of a Window.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the size and position of the second window:

```
Window win = new Window()
{
    Left = this.Left,
    Top = this.Top,
    Width = this.Width,
    Height = this.Height
};
win.Show();
```

`this` refers to the current window in the above sample code.